# Network IO throttling in cgroups

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

cgroups allow the user to manage the resource usages of processes or groups of processes. Block IO throttling is supported and works well. Why is it however that network IO throttling (specifying hard limits on the bandwidth) of a process not supported? Userspace applications like trickle do exist to do the same. Why not integrate it with the cgroups framework?

Thanks.